# Draw an overlay in tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I need to be helped especially in drawing the conical flask inside an overlay circle as shown in the image below:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}[1][]{enhanced,breakable, 
before skip=2mm, 
after skip=2mm, 
colback=white, 
colframe=red!75!black, 
boxrule=0.7mm, 
bottomtitle=0.04cm,%space after title
sharp corners, 
width=10cm, 
%%controlling arc at the bottom right
rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=4.5mm, 
fonttitle=\bf\sffamily, coltitle=black, 
overlay={\draw[fill=white,white]([xshift=.23cm,yshift=-.36cm]frame.north 
west)circle(11.2pt);%white circle
\draw[red!75!black,fill=red!75!black]([xshift=.18cm,yshift=-.36cm]frame.north 
west)circle(11.2pt); %red circle
}, 
title={\hspace*{.2cm}\color{white}{ #1}} 
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{mybox2}[Practical skills] 
\raggedright
These boxes identify the key practical skills you need to understand as part 
of completing\\ the course. 
\end{mybox2} 
\end{document}
```

gives the image below:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `fontawesome5 ` package has `\faFlask`, which you could use instead of drawing your own icon …

Comment: You can also do `texdoc comprehensive` and search for symbols provided by fonts (including fontawesome). Otherwise, perhaps https://www.ctan.org/pkg/proflabo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the @Jasper Habicht advise.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} %<--- Added this line
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}[1][]{enhanced,breakable, 
before skip=2mm, 
after skip=2mm, 
colback=white, 
colframe=red!75!black, 
boxrule=0.7mm, 
bottomtitle=0.04cm,%space after title
sharp corners, 
width=10cm, 
%%controlling arc at the bottom right
rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=4.5mm, 
fonttitle=\bf\sffamily, coltitle=black, 
overlay={\draw[fill=white,white]
([xshift=.23cm,yshift=-.36cm]frame.north west)circle(11.2pt);%white circle
\draw[red!75!black,fill=red!75!black]    
([xshift=.18cm,yshift=-.36cm]frame.north 
west)circle(11.2pt) node[white]{\faFlask};}, %<-- Added node[white]{\faFlask} 
title={\hspace*{.2cm}\color{white}{ #1}}} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{mybox2}[Practical skills] 
\raggedright
These boxes identify the key practical skills you need to understand 
as part of completing\\ the course. 
\end{mybox2} 
\end{document}
```

Which give us the result
[image]

I hope this help you with your typing.